# Issue installing MongoDB on alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

```
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update
RUN apk add mongodb==3.4.4-r0

RUN mongo --version
```

it show errors

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  so:libboost_chrono-mt.so.1.62.0 (missing):
    required by:
                 mongodb-3.4.4-r0[so:libboost_chrono-mt.so.1.62.0]
  so:libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.62.0 (missing):
    required by:
                 mongodb-3.4.4-r0[so:libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.62.0]
  so:libboost_iostreams-mt.so.1.62.0 (missing):
    required by:
                 mongodb-3.4.4-r0[so:libboost_iostreams-mt.so.1.62.0]
  so:libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.62.0 (missing):
    required by:
                 mongodb-3.4.4-r0[so:libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.62.0]
  so:libboost_regex-mt.so.1.62.0 (missing):
    required by:
                 mongodb-3.4.4-r0[so:libboost_regex-mt.so.1.62.0]
  so:libboost_system-mt.so.1.62.0 (missing):
    required by:
                 mongodb-3.4.4-r0[so:libboost_system-mt.so.1.62.0]
  so:libboost_thread-mt.so.1.62.0 (missing):
    required by:
                 mongodb-3.4.4-r0[so:libboost_thread-mt.so.1.62.0]
  so:libcrypto.so.41 (missing):
    required by:
                 mongodb-3.4.4-r0[so:libcrypto.so.41]
  so:libssl.so.43 (missing):
```

Answer (score 27):

MongoDB version `3.4.4-r0` is located in [Alpine v3.6 community](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community) repository and requires another packages like `boost`, `boost-iostreams`, `boost-dev` etc version `1.62.0-r5` to be installed. They are only available in [Alpine v3.6 main](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community) repository. You just need to add that repository to alpine repository's list as well:

```
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update
RUN apk add mongodb=3.4.4-r0

RUN mongo --version
```

Comment: Let me try with your post.

Comment: yes,success. the key is http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main.

Comment: How can these old packages be installed if alpine is new versions?

Comment: @focuszheng When packet manager tries to install `mongodb' of some version, it resolves its dependencies and then just looks for those packages with their versions in all repositories we have.

Comment: ,okay,the key is append the specific repositories to the /etc/apk/repositories.

Comment: I tried this method, it installed mongodb yes, but also bringing other old versions of other tools like python (e.g 3.6.9 to be exact, and this version has some reported vulnerability from OWASP check), but if Python in installed with the version in the base alpine (3.12 in my case), 3.8, there won't be any vulnerability. How do I avoid this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me... probably it will work for you as well

```
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update
RUN apk add mongodb=3.4.4-r0

VOLUME ["/data/db"]
WORKDIR /data
EXPOSE 27017
```

Use /data folder because it is the defult one. Other names will give you error.

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk add --no-cache mongodb

VOLUME /data/db
EXPOSE 27017 28017

COPY run.sh /root
ENTRYPOINT [ "/root/run.sh" ]
CMD [ "mongod", "--bind_ip", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

Where run.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Docker entrypoint (pid 1), run as root
[ "$1" = "mongod" ] || exec "$@" || exit $?

# Make sure that database is owned by user mongodb
[ "$(stat -c %U /data/db)" = mongodb ] || chown -R mongodb /data/db

# Drop root privilege (no way back), exec provided command as user mongodb
cmd=exec; for i; do cmd="$cmd '$i'"; done
exec su -s /bin/sh -c "$cmd" mongodb
```

Comment: my base image is alpine:3.8

Comment: and I just wanna install mongodb==3.4.4-r0

Comment: I'm getting an error with this. `ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: mongodb (missing): required by: world[mongodb]`

Comment: This won't work anymore since mongodb was removed from alpine 3.10. https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.10.0-released.html check Significant Removals section.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mongodb-*.tgz packages for linux legacy x64 in official website:
- https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.6.17.tgz
- https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-4.0.17.tgz
...
These can work normally in alpine linux 3.11.